# List of nonverbal expressions of primary and secondary emotions

Tags: emotion, evolutionary-psychology

I'm currently looking for reliable scientific sources that might help me with rating emotions in video-material. Ideally a comprehensive list of facial-/postural expressions of primary and secondary emotions.

Comment: Related: [List of affective states for a study?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/7679/7001), [Standard Academic set of emotions, and cognitive functions](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17265/7001)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of affective states for a study?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/list-of-affective-states-for-a-study)

Comment: The standard for facial movements is [FACS](http://www.paulekman.com/product-category/facs/), although the system is not without its criticisms.  There's also something called the [BACS](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17470919.2014.890668), which attempts a similar feat as FACS but with body muscles.